# Childbrowser not opening webpage in ios phonegap 1.3

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

We've been using childbrowser for a while to open pdfs in our ios app with no problems.  Recently we decided to open a webpage that we were opening in safari in childbrowser, so I split the pdf specific code off from the original webpage opening code and tried to get the window to come up.  This, of course, did not work.  After trying for a while to get it to work I decided to just make a blank phonegap project, put the childbrowser plugin in and get it to go to google (as in the example).

New phonegap 1.3 project, new fresh childbrowser plugin added (in xcode as a yellow folder in the plugin folder), js for childbrowser added to www folder and to index.html, and added google.com; ChildBrowser/ChildBrowser.js; ChildBrowserCommand/ChildBrowserCommand to phonegap.plist.  Then I tried the three different ways I know how to try to open a childbrowser page (shouldStartLoadWithRequest in appdelegate, call the childbrowser javascript, or call the method directly using phonegap.exec) and none of them worked.

Is there something different I have to do to make childbrowser work for 1.3?  Or am I missing a step to get webpages to work in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off I figured out that you need to both set up appdelegate to sent the proper pages to childbrowser AND you need to use code to submit the url using childbrowser.

Second, www.google.com does not work, www.google.com/ does.